# how to uninstall php7

Tags: uninstall, php7

How to uninstall php 7 on. I was trying to manage two different websites with two different versions of php (5.6 and 7), but it didn't work, so I need to uninstall both versions and to install one clear version.

Comment: How did you install them?

Comment: Note that it is possible to run multiple versions of PHP simultaneously using PHP-FPM and any server supporting fastCGI like Apache or nginx.  Setup into [here](https://pehapkari.cz/blog/2017/03/27/multiple-php-versions-the-easy-way/).  If you need help on this it'd need to be in a separate question though.

Comment: This question should be removed because @gordon was "Last seen more than 6 years ago" ....

Answer (score 0):

Try opening a terminal window (Alt-Ctrl-T) and running `sudo apt purge php7.0`

Comment: If it worked please mark the question on this site as accepted (theres the button for that under the up/down arrows left hand of your question)

Answer (score -1):

Type `sudo apt purge php` and hit `tab` and you will get all the installed php packages listed in the terminal. You can remove or keep the packages as you wish.

Update the package lists in the system and install PHP with following command:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install php7.0
```